# Merge android-market, market

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

- [market](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/market) 19
- [android-market](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/android-market) 11

Answer (score 2):

Market. Less is more.

Comment: Agreed.  And android is redundant

Comment: Additionally, we've already blacklisted the 'android' tag here: http://meta.android.stackexchange.com/questions/17/can-we-black-list-the-android-tag